# SetPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number using React and Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to display multiple markers using google maps and react but keep getting the error mentioned above. The idea is to have multiple markers displayed from lat and long cords in an array. Any thoughts?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evOoNP?editors=0010

```
class GMap extends React.Component {
  state = { zoom: 10 };

  static propTypes() {
    initialCenter: React.PropTypes.objectOf(React.PropTypes.number).isRequired
  }

    render() {
    return <div className="GMap">
      <div className='UpdatedText'>
        <p>Current Zoom: { this.state.zoom }</p>
      </div>
      <div className='GMap-canvas' ref="mapCanvas">
      </div>
    </div>
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // create the map, marker and infoWindow after the component has
    // been rendered because we need to manipulate the DOM for Google =(
    this.map = this.createMap()
    this.marker = this.createMarker()
    this.infoWindow = this.createInfoWindow()

    // have to define google maps event listeners here too
    // because we can't add listeners on the map until its created
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', ()=> this.handleZoomChange())
  }

  // clean up event listeners when component unmounts
  componentDidUnMount() {
    google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'zoom_changed')
  }

  createMap() {
    let mapOptions = {
      zoom: this.state.zoom,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(38, -78)
    }
    return new google.maps.Map(this.refs.mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }

  mapCenters() {
    return new google.maps.LatLng(
      this.props.initialCenter.lat,
      this.props.initialCenter.lng
    )
  }

  mapCenter() {

    const navLinks = [
        {location: "Bondi Beach", lat: -33.890542, long: 151.274856},
        {location: "Coogee Beach", lat: -33.923036, long: 151.259052},
        {location: "Cronulla Beach", lat: -34.028249, long: 151.157507}
    ];
    return navLinks.map((b, i) => {
      console.log(b)
      return new google.maps.LatLng(b.lat, b.long)
    })
  }

  createMarker() {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: this.mapCenter(),
      map: this.map
    })
    }

  createInfoWindow() {
    let contentString = "<div class='InfoWindow'>I'm a Window that contains Info Yay</div>"
    return new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      map: this.map,
      anchor: this.marker,
      content: contentString
    })
  }

  handleZoomChange() {
    this.setState({
      zoom: this.map.getZoom()
    })
  }
}

var initialCenter = { lng: -90.1056957, lat: 29.9717272 }

ReactDOM.render(<GMap initialCenter={initialCenter} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: this.mapCenter(), // here is the problem
    map: this.map
})
```

Your `mapCenter()` method returns an array of coordinates, but `new google.maps.Marker({})` expects a single `LatLng` to be passed as `position`.

You need to update your `createMarker()` method to create the markers in a loop, for example:

```
createMarker() {
return this.mapCenter().map( point => {
  return new google.maps.Marker({
    position: point,
    map: this.map
  })
});
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMLYBa?editors=0010